# maquetar tabla dinámica php

Tags: php, html, html-tabla, tabla-dinámica

Estoy tratando de maquetar los resultados que vienen desde mi controlador en array asociativo que contiene otros arrays:

```
$licencias_asr = array(
            'version'    => array("ASR8", "ASR9"),
            'servidores' => array(8,5),
            'licencias'  => array(560, 350),
        );
```

necesito hacer una tabla con esta estructura:

```
<table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
              <td>Version</td>
              <td>Servidores</td>
              <td>Licencias</td>
           </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
           <tr>
             <td>ASR8</td>
             <td>8</td>
             <td>560</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>ASR9</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>350</td>
         </tr>
     </tbody>
 </table>
```

en php estoy intentando recrear esa estructura de esta forma:

```
<?php 
    $table_headers_asr = "<table class='table'>
                            <thead><tr>";

     $table_body_asr = "<tbody>";
                                                
     foreach($licencias_asr as $key => $value){
         $table_headers_asr .= "<th>".$key."</th>";
     }
     $table_headers_asr .= "</tr></thead>";
     foreach($licencias_asr["version"] as $key => $version){
        $table_body_asr .= "<tr><td>".$version;
     }

     foreach($licencias_asr["servidores"] as $key => $servidor){
       $table_body_asr .= "<td>".$servidor."</td>";
       $table_body_asr .= "<td>".($servidor * 70)."</td>";
       $table_body_asr .= "</tr></tbody>";
     }
     $table_body_asr .= "</table>";
     echo $table_headers_asr . $table_body_asr;
 ?>
```

Pero no consigo hacer que me coincidan los rows como en la tabla html que adjunto, me queda toda desordenada.

¿Como podría generar esta tabla dinámica con php?

Gracias y un saludo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con esto (las explicaciones están en los comentarios del código):

```php
<?php
// array multidimensional inicial con los datos
$licencias_asr = array(
    'version'    => array("ASR8", "ASR9"),
    'servidores' => array(8,5),
    'licencias'  => array(560, 350),
 );

// iniciamos variables a usar
$cabeceras_tabla = '';
$fila = [];

// recorremos el array inicial
foreach ($licencias_asr as $th_thead => $array_valores) {
    // Agrupamos las cabeceras y le ponemos la mayúscula
    $cabeceras_tabla .= '
            <th>'.ucfirst($th_thead).'</th>';
    // separamos los valores de los array por fila
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($array_valores); $i++) {
        // si no existe esa fila la inicializamos
        if (!isset($fila[$i])) {
            $fila[$i] = '';
        }
        // agregamos el contenido en el mismo índice de fila
        $fila[$i] .= '
            <td>'.$array_valores[$i].'</td>';
    }
}

// inicializamos la variable para agrupar las filas
$filas = '';

// Agrupamos las filas, contando primero cuantos valores contienen
// y agregamos sus columnas
for ($i = 0; $i < count(array_values($licencias_asr)[0]); $i++) {
    $filas .= '
        <tr>'.$fila[$i].'
        </tr>';
}

// componemos la salida
$salida_html = '<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>'.$cabeceras_tabla.';
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>'.$filas.'
    </tbody>
</table>' ;

echo $salida_html;
```

Como puedes observar, lo hago en dos pasos, para que primero se puedan agrupar las columnas en cada fila, y luego recorro las filas a crear y voy agregando las columnas obtenidas en cada una de ellas.

Comment: muchisimas gracias!! funciona estupendo